# Filter objects if one to many relationship not exists

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two models:

```
ModelA:
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

ModelB:
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
titlecomponent = models.ForeignKey('ModelA',on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

How can i get all objects of ModelA which have not any record relationsip in ModelB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by comparing with `None`:

```
ModelA.objects.filter(modelb=None)
```

The reason this works is because a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is performed, and thus if no related `ModelB` exists, then a row that contains `NULL`s is added.

This will thus boil down to a query that looks like:

```
SELECT app_modela.*
FROM app_modela
LEFT OUTER JOIN app_modelb ON app_modelb.titlecomponent = app.modela.id
WHERE app_modelb.id IS NULL
```